# cassandra state listener sends duplicate signals one with public ip and another with private ip

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-cli

I have a 5 node cassandra cluster and the listen_address in each nodes are configured with its private address in cassandra.yml.

**Config looks like below :**
**NOTE: 192.168.1.* is a private ip address**

```
cassandra 1| listen_address:192.168.1.1  | publicip :kafka1/x.y.z.1  
cassandra 2| listen_address:192.168.1.2  | publicip :kafka2/x.y.z.2  
cassandra 3| listen_address:192.168.1.3  | publicip :kafka3/x.y.z.3  
cassandra 4| listen_address:192.168.1.4  | publicip :kafka4/x.y.z.4  
cassandra 5| listen_address:192.168.1.5  | publicip :kafka5/x.y.z.5
```

I also have a java program which acts as Cassandra state listener listening on onAdd,onUp,onDown ,onRemove call's.

**NOTE** : Java program talk's to cassandra via public domain name
(E.G) cassandra_hosts:kafka1,kafka2,kafka3,kafka4

```
    {
    private Set<Host> downHostList = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Host>());
    //onup/onAdd Implemetation
    public void onAdd(Host host) {      
            if(downHostList.contains(host)){
                downHostList.remove(host);
            }
            LOG.info("Down host count {} and the list is[{}]",downHostList.size(),downHostList);        
        }
        //onDown/OnRemove Implentation
        public void onDown(Host host) {
            if(!host.isUp()){
                downHostList.add(host);
            }
            LOG.info("Down host count {} and the list is[{}]",downHostList.size(),downHostList);
        }  
}
```

**Below is the observation from the output :**
When i bring node 2 down i see that onDown is called twice .one time i got the public ip address and the next time i got the private ip address .So the count was 
[image]

**Update :NOV 2**
  Though i don't have an answer for this .My workaround for this is to use the private ip in my java program to talk to Cassandra .. I will continue to use this as i wait for some on from Cassandra community answers this ..

Comment: You're using the DataStax Java driver for this program?

Comment: yes .http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/2.1.4

Answer (score 2):

The datastax java driver receives these notifications from C* over a designated connection to one of your C* nodes using the ['STATUS_CHANGE'](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.2.0/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec#L730) event subscription.  Ultimately UP & DOWN events are detected via information that the C* node receives from gossip and C* sends an event for the rpc_address or broadcast_rpc_address of that host (with broadcast_rpc_address taking precedence).

I'm assuming you are configuring rpc_address in cassandra.yaml to these 192.168.1.x addresses right?

It's possible there is a bug in C* (what versions are you on of C* and the driver?).  Another possibility is that the peers information may be somehow corrupted so the driver may see x.y.z.2 and 192.168.1.2 as separate hosts (I don't anticipate that).  Did you originally use the public ips as your rpc_address and then change to private later?  One thing that would be good to check is that state of the system.peers table on each C* node by executing the following command in cqlsh on each node:

```
select peer,rpc_address from system.peers;
```

to see if x.y.z.2 shows up as rpc_address on any of your hosts.

Comment: thanks for your response .. Below are the details ..Java Datastax driver version : cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar ..  Cassandra version :2.1.5 ..rpc_address in all cassandra nodes where private ip .

Comment: As a work around i just updated my java application to use the private IP address to talk to cassandra . This woraround seems to work ..